# Code for group programatically fields on edit form similar to Flexifield

Tags: 6, entities

I am looking how programmatically to group fields on edit form similar to [Flexifield](http://drupal.org/project/flexifield).  The idea is group in the edit form some fields unlimited.  I want to group the fields like as shown in the next link:

http://blog.merge.nl/2009/08/05/multiple-fieldsets-cck-multigroup

I have tried the [Flexifield](http://drupal.org/project/flexifield) module but has a lot of errors and poor support.

I am working with drupal 6.x.

Thanks very much!!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the first link on that page? To the [dev version of CCK](http://drupal.org/node/484068)? I just had to do this very thing this morning. The dev version of CCK has an additional module included with it called multigroup. You create a new field of the multigroup type, then add all the fields you want to include in it. Set the number of repeats on the multigroup to unlimited, and you (or your users) can then add as many groups as necessary.

Comment: Actually I cannot to implement this option because the version is in dev, however is a great option, works fine for me and I hope that soon the version is available for production. do you know if only the dev version has this feature?  thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's only in the dev version for now. But the dev version has been out for a long time, and it's pretty stable.

Comment: It's good to know it.  It's a great alternative.  The flexifield module is poorly supported.  I tried the dev version of CCK and works for me.  Thanks again.